# How to store output from list manipulation to a variable

Tags: python, variables

Trying to write a program that generates random pw and stores that information in a variable that can be used to populate a mysql database.

I am able to generate the random password but am struggling to figure out how to store that information in a variable.

Here is the password generate code:

```
import random
from random import randint
import string

letters = (list(string.hexdigits + '!@#$%^&*_'))
word = []
length = randint(8, 16) 

for i in range(1, length):
    char = random.choice(letters)
    word.append(char)
for x in range(len(word)):
    print(word[x], end = '')
```

It prints out the randomly generated password nicely, but what I want is to store that in a variable that can be used later. So far, nothing I have tried has worked.

Do you have any hints about how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I am assuming you need to generate a password of length `length`, so in this case, you are not using correctly the `range` function. It can be fixed simply by changing `range(1, length)` to `range(length)`.

As you have stated, the password is generated correctly in the list `word`, so now you just have to join the elements of this list, and store the result in a variable, let's call it `generated_password`:

```
generated_password = ''.join(word)
```

Alternatively, you can also simplify your code using the following:

```
generated_password = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(length))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, also, nice catch on the range(length) issue. Frustrating thing is that at one point I KNEW this and forgot.

Comment: @RobertBaker, no worries [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) is one of the most common errors in programming.